# Error: Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php7, codeigniter-3, session

Actualmente tengo un problema con mi controlador Session.php

cuando intento ingresa a esa vista me arroja este error: Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Estoy trabajando en php 7 y codeigniter 3.1, anteriomente funcionaba porque lo usaba con php 5.6 y codeigniter 2.6.

```js
mi config.php

$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'sessions';
```

```css
Mi outoload.php  :
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

```html
mi controlador 

class Session extends CI_Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent:: __construct();
  if($this->session->userdata('perfil') == FALSE || $this->session->userdata('perfil') != '2')
  {
   redirect(base_url('init/login'));
  }
  $this->load->model('msession');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->library('breadcrumbs');
  $this->load->model('mmaterial');
  $this->load->model('mevaluacion');
  $this->load->model('mcurso');
  $this->load->model('mtarea');
 }
```

Comment: Declara la clase así: **`class Session extends MX_Controller`** en vez de `class Session extends CI_Controller` y dinos si funciona.

Comment: A. cedano lo actualice pero me sale: esta pagina no funciona.

Comment: ¿Cómo quedó la declaración de la clase?

Comment: class Session extends MX_Controller a si quedo el controlador

Comment: Otra sugerencia es cambiarlo por `extends CI_Model` , puedes ver [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29841942/5587982) donde se trató un problema similar al tuyo.

Comment: Es un controlador, no le puedo poner model porque asumiría que es un modelo. Ya vi ese post y probé todas las sugerencias pero no me ayudaron, otra problema que pueda tener ?

Comment: extends CI_Model no podría poner este porque en mi caso si esta bien el nombre de mi modelo